# Secure signals on boot time to prevent unwanted operations

Tags: hardware, fpga, system-verilog, hdl

**How can I be sure that at boot time my module won't get random values to it's control signals and write to an address* before I reset the module?**

*(or anything that shouldn't be done before reset)

If the question is considered too general: I'm trying to make some code in System verilog with a Xilinx Zynq platform as a target device in mind.

Comment: You use a power-on-reset circuit to assure that the reset signal is asserted as the power supplies ramp up.

Comment: @toolic Can you expand more on that with an answer?

Comment: An answer is beyond the scope of Verilog: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_reset

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when an FPGA is powered on and left unconfigured?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34378/what-happens-when-an-fpga-is-powered-on-and-left-unconfigured)

Comment: @SimonRichter It's very different: I'm concerned about what will happen to the module itself (it shouldn't be left unprotected at start cause I may get random I/O signals), I won't try to leave the fpga unconfigured or try to figure something that would harm the board itself.

Comment: You need to elaborate on where your I/O signals are coming from. Inside or outside the FPGA?

Comment: @mng Let me elaborate: The concern was raised while trying to design (my very first) FSM for the Amba axi-4 protocol. Then the thought of having random operations before asserting the reset signal was a nightmare. The inputs and outputs will come either directly from a single Master either from an interconnect component (more likely). So I supose all signals will be internal (I'd like to emmbed the module to a larger system).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you wouldn't be able to use the AXI peripheral reset?

Comment: @mng that do you mean? Is that in the specification? (I'm very new to all these)

Comment: @user2692669, at least it should cover the FPGA side of things: the FPGA is passive, and you should have both an active-low and an active-high output that remains active until the FPGA has been loaded and regular operation started, and these can be used to keep the rest of the logic in reset state.

Comment: If you're making an AXI peripheral you should have an ARESETn input. Build up a Zynq block diagram and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

During the boot sequence the I/O-pins are usualy pulled up with high impedance so they can not damage other parts. For the registers and the memory of the FPGA you can define the initialization with the constraints editor.

If you build the PCB yourself it's your job (with the help of the data sheets) to provide the appropriate reset signals (perhaps sequential) to the various parts. Eventually you will need also some pull-up or pull-down resistors or additional logic. You also have the possibility to control the startup of other parts/modules with your FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kitana's assessment, to clarify, the usual start-up sequence of an FPGA is something like this:

power rails come up -> FPGA is configured -> reset is issued to FPGA -> the reset statements in your code set the IO to known states.

Hope this helps